How to Create Word,Excel,PowerPoint,Outlook Icons in desktop using Intune?
I used this script in Intune to create an MS Excel Icon on the desktop of users' machine.
$TargetFile = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.exe"
$DesktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$ShortcutFile = "$DesktopPath\Excel.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Save()

When I try to use it for Word I get an error in Intune and I don't know why?
$TargetFile = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.exe"
$DesktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$ShortcutFile = "$DesktopPath\Word.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Save()


If I want to combine all of it into 1 script how do I do this?
At the moment I've created a separate script for each of the MS application
Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Outlook, Onenote
Thanks
use the same script but amend the name of the file to create a shortcut on the desktop

I would say this is the simplest way by code
    # Paths to Office programs
$OfficePrograms = @{
    "Word" = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.exe"
    "PowerPoint" = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\POWERPNT.exe"
    "Excel" = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.exe"
}

# Path to the user's desktop
$DesktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")

# Create shortcuts for each program
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

foreach ($Program in $OfficePrograms.Keys) {
    # Path to the program file
    $TargetFile = $OfficePrograms[$Program]
    
    # Path to the shortcut on the desktop
    $ShortcutFile = "$DesktopPath\$Program.lnk"
    
    # Create the shortcut
    $Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
    $Shortcut.IconLocation = "$TargetFile, 0" # Set the program icon
    $Shortcut.Description = "Shortcut to Microsoft $Program"
    $Shortcut.Save()
}

Write-Host "Shortcuts for Office programs have been successfully created on the desktop."

